# How to enforce web.config entries for one site collection in SP 2010 web farm

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-config, sitecollection

in our web farm we have a Site Collection that requires specific settings in web.config.

The installation instructions describe to manually edit web.config and add some entries to appSettings, system.WebServer/modules, system.WebServer/handlers and system.serviceModel.

We see that web.configs are overwritten sometimes, and some of the settings that we added are removed automatically.

Our consultants tell us it is no option to include settings in WSP, because this way settings will be applied to all web.configs in Farm, not only in our Site Collection. Is this true?

What is the recommended way for ensuring certain web config settings are guaranteed in the web configuration of 1 site collection?

Thanks,
Wouter

Answer (score 0):

Web.config is related to Web application, not to site collection. So all site collections within one web application share one web.config.

You can create WSP package containing feature with feature receiver and SPWebConfigModification in it. It can apply web.config modifications to all web.configs of the same web application in the farm so you need not to "sync" them manually.